# Двойное срабатывание события Click

Tags: c#, mvp

Здравствйте. Я пытаюсь реализовать паттерн проектирования MVP. Изначально были созданы три обычных кнопки button. После завершения проекта, решил изменить дизайн кнопок и ничего не придумал, как реализовать их через picturebox. И вот после изменения в проекте всех частей с button на picturebox событие стало срабатывать дважды. (Я просто изменил все места с указанием button на picturebox). Ниже приведу код. Первый "файл" это view, второй prosenter.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace HumanAsSystem
    {
        public interface IMainForms
        {
            event EventHandler ClickTask1;
            event EventHandler ClickTask2;
            event EventHandler ClickTask3;
        }
        public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainForms
        {
            #region Релизация IMainForms
            public event EventHandler ClickTask1;
            public event EventHandler ClickTask2;
            public event EventHandler ClickTask3;
            #endregion 
            public MainForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Button1PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button1PictureBox_Click);
                Button2PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button2PictureBox_Click);
                Button3PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button3PictureBox_Click);
    
            }
            #region События
            
            private void Button1PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ClickTask1 != null)
                {
                    ClickTask1(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
    
            private void Button2PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ClickTask2 != null)
                {
                    ClickTask2(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
    
            private void Button3PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ClickTask3 != null)
                {
                    ClickTask3(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
    
            #endregion
    
            private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
```

Вот мой presenter

```
 using System;
 using HumanAsSystemTask1;
 using HumanAsSystemTask2;
 using HumanAsSystemTask3;

  namespace HumanAsSystem
 {
    class MainPresenter
    {
        private readonly IMainForms _mainform;
        private readonly MS.IMessageService _message_service;

        public MainPresenter (IMainForms mainform, MS.IMessageService message_service)
        {
            _mainform = mainform;
            _message_service = message_service;


            _mainform.ClickTask1 +=  new EventHandler(_mainform_ClickTask1);
            _mainform.ClickTask2 += new EventHandler(_mainform_ClickTask2);
            _mainform.ClickTask3 += new EventHandler(_mainform_ClickTask3);
        }

        void _mainform_ClickTask1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task1Form form1 = new Task1Form();
            form1.Show();
        }
        void _mainform_ClickTask2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task2Form form2 = new Task2Form();
            form2.Show();
        }
        void _mainform_ClickTask3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task3Form form3 = new Task3Form();
            form3.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

В С# не очень шарю, больше по с++. Поставили задачу сделать, и вот сталкиваюсь с разными проблемами и ничего не могу сообразить. Из-за различныз проблем и так выпилил часть функционала

MainFormDesigner

```
namespace HumanAsSystem
{
    partial class MainForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Button3PictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.Button2PictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.Button1PictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button3PictureBox)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button2PictureBox)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button1PictureBox)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Button3PictureBox
            // 
            this.Button3PictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.Button3PictureBox.Image = global::HumanAsSystem.Properties.Resources.Button3Up;
            this.Button3PictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 168);
            this.Button3PictureBox.Name = "Button3PictureBox";
            this.Button3PictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 60);
            this.Button3PictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.Button3PictureBox.TabIndex = 5;
            this.Button3PictureBox.TabStop = false;
            this.Button3PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_Click);
            this.Button3PictureBox.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_MouseDown);
            this.Button3PictureBox.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_MouseEnter);
            this.Button3PictureBox.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_MouseLeave);
            this.Button3PictureBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_MouseUp);
            // 
            // Button2PictureBox
            // 
            this.Button2PictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.Button2PictureBox.Image = global::HumanAsSystem.Properties.Resources.Button2Up;
            this.Button2PictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 102);
            this.Button2PictureBox.Name = "Button2PictureBox";
            this.Button2PictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 60);
            this.Button2PictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.Button2PictureBox.TabIndex = 4;
            this.Button2PictureBox.TabStop = false;
            this.Button2PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_Click);
            this.Button2PictureBox.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_MouseDown);
            this.Button2PictureBox.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_MouseEnter);
            this.Button2PictureBox.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_MouseLeave);
            this.Button2PictureBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_MouseUp);
            // 
            // Button1PictureBox
            // 
            this.Button1PictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
            this.Button1PictureBox.Image = global::HumanAsSystem.Properties.Resources.Button1Up;
            this.Button1PictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 36);
            this.Button1PictureBox.Name = "Button1PictureBox";
            this.Button1PictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 60);
            this.Button1PictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.Button1PictureBox.TabIndex = 3;
            this.Button1PictureBox.TabStop = false;
            this.Button1PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_Click);
            this.Button1PictureBox.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_MouseDown);
            this.Button1PictureBox.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_MouseEnter);
            this.Button1PictureBox.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_MouseLeave);
            this.Button1PictureBox.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_MouseUp);
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(207)))), ((int)(((byte)(213)))), ((int)(((byte)(225)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(502, 270);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Button3PictureBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Button2PictureBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Button1PictureBox);
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.Text = "MainForm";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button3PictureBox)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button2PictureBox)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Button1PictureBox)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox Button1PictureBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox Button2PictureBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox Button3PictureBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите MainForm.Designer.cs

Comment: aepot, добавил. Я вроде его смотрел, но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас происходит дважды подписывание на события `Click`.

В конструкторе:

```cs
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Button1PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button1PictureBox_Click);
    Button2PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button2PictureBox_Click);
    Button3PictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(Button3PictureBox_Click);
}
```

И в `InitializeComponent()` (задается в дизайнере формы):

```cs
this.Button3PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button3PictureBox_Click);
this.Button2PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2PictureBox_Click);
this.Button1PictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1PictureBox_Click);
```

Сколько раз подписались - столько раз и сработает.

Либо уберите в дизайнере подписывание на события, либо в конструкторе формы.

Comment: Я все осознал!! Спасибо огромное!!! Я теперь понял почему у меня еще часть вещей не работала)